# Google app engine, objectify how to order by a sub entity field?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I have a Course  entity that contains the following field

```
@Index
private @Load
Ref<Student> student;
```

The student entity then has the field

```
 @Index
private String matric;
```

I want to load all the Course entities **sorted** using the students matric number.

I have tried using the "." operator to get the sub field like this

```
ofy().load().type(Course.class).filter("course", course).order("student.matric").list();
```

but this return no result.

Is it possible to do this? how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that is possible with objectify. I would let Course implement Comparable:

```
@Entity
public class Course implements Comparable<Course> {
    .
    .
    .
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Course otherCourse) {
        return this.getStudent().getMatric().compareTo(otherCourse.getStudent().getMatric());
    }
}
```

Remove the "order" part of the Objectify load and use Collections.sort() instead:

```
List<Course> courses = ofy().load().type(Course.class).filter("course", course).list();
Collections.sort(courses);
```

Comment: Sorry for the errors in the first post. Now corrected :)

Comment: Thanks, I am not really interested in sorting the result after getting it. What I am interested in is getting the data from the data store sorted, because I am not using it for this implementation alone. Where I need is most is where the result is paginated, if I get an unsorted result then sort it using any field the result would be confusing to the user.

Answer (score 1):

There are no joins in the datastore. If you want to query your Courses by Student properties, you probably will need to denormalize the data into the Course and index it. This means changing the Student data will also require changing Courses.

As an aside: This data model is weird. Are you sure what you're calling Course isn't really an Enrollment?

Comment: Yeah, its an enrollment. I called it course for simplicity on stackoverflow, the enrollment has course as a field in it. Thanks.